# How to match elements with a nested vector colum?

Tags: r, nested-tibble

I am trying to see how the elements in nested vector match with the Order ID from Order_ID column and I'm not quite sure how to match them together. For example:

[image]

I would like to create code to match the Order ID with the separate element in the nested vector. For example, I hope to see

[image]

I have tried using `unlist()` to extract the elements out from the nested vector but I'm still not sure how to match them with the Order ID. Is there any way to solve this problem? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a reproducible example of your issue:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x = letters[1:3],
             a = list(1L, 2:3, 4:6),
             b = list(LETTERS[1], LETTERS[2:3], LETTERS[4:6]))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   x     a         b        
#>   <chr> <list>    <list>   
#> 1 a     <int [1]> <chr [1]>
#> 2 b     <int [2]> <chr [2]>
#> 3 c     <int [3]> <chr [3]>

View(df)
```

[image]

And here how you can solve it:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(x) %>% 
 summarise(across(c(a,b), unlist), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   x         a b    
#>   <chr> <int> <chr>
#> 1 a         1 A    
#> 2 b         2 B    
#> 3 b         3 C    
#> 4 c         4 D    
#> 5 c         5 E    
#> 6 c         6 F
```

You need to set in `group_by` all the variables that you want to keep and be replicated (in this case `x`) and in across all the variables that you want to unlist (in this case `c(a, b)`).

`across` will apply `unlist` to each column, by keeping in consideration the groups.

I believe in your case the code should be:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(Order_ID) %>% 
 summarise(across(c(Product, Price, Quantity), unlist), .groups = "drop")
```